# Specifiying Default Value for Datetime property in FluenNhibernate mapping class

Tags: datetime, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

imagine we have an object have a property:

```
//the date which app has been added to the system
    public virtual DateTime SubmitionDate { get; set; }
```

how can I set default value (current date) for `SubmutionDate` in the sqlServer 2008 using mapping class?

I did like this but it doesn't work and raise an sqlDateTimeException!

```
 Map(x => x.SubmitionDate).Default(System.DateTime.Now.ToString()).Not.Nullable();
```

Answer (score 3):

The mapping is being processed only when your session factory is being created. Therefore you can't specify the date directly in mapping.

You can however specify the SQL (or rather HQL) function instead like this:

```
Map(x => x.SubmitionDate).Default("getdate()").Not.Nullable();
```